# What 1x8 ski part is this?

Tags: part-identification

I looked through the usual places BrickLink/Rebrickable. I can't seem to find what part this is. It has no markings other then `Lego` and `LEGO Group`. I seem to remember it going to a set where this singular ski part goes in the front.

[image: part]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be item No. 2823

- [**Technic Forklift Fork (white)**](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2823&name=Technic%20Forklift%20Fork&category=%5BTechnic%5D#T=S&C=1&O=%7B%22color%22:1,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

It was part of four sets:

[6342-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6342-1) **Beach Rescue Chopper**

[image]

---

[6545-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6545-1) **Search N' Rescue**

[image]

---

[6401-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6401-1) **Seaside Cabana**

[image]

---

[6663-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6663-1) **Wave Rebel**

[image]

*All images bricklink*

Comment: Thank you so much! 6342 is the set I think..